# Database access with Spring and Jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am new with spring and now I am accessing to a database and showing the results in a jsp. This is the xml file I use to connect with the database:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.11:3306/databasename" />
    <property name="username" value="****" />
    <property name="password" value="****" />
</bean>

<bean id="Am_facultyentityDAO" class="com.bdAlmamater.model.Am_facultyentityJdbcDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="Am_campusentityDAO" class="com.bdAlmamater.model.Am_campusentityJdbcDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

It all works fine, but I have a lot of tables in my database and I would like to know if I have to put for each table something like this:

```
 <bean id="Am_campusentityDAO" class="com.bdAlmamater.model.Am_campusentityJdbcDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

or is it a shorter way to write it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is using a version of Spring that is a decade old. Look at Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare your classes in bean configuration file everytime, you could use Spring's stereo types (like Component, Service, Repository and Controller) to identify your classes.

In order to use this stereotypes,

You need to first specify

```
 <content:componet-scan  base-package="com.bdAlmamater.model" >
```

and specify packages to scan (i.e packages where your stereo type annotated class exists )

If you are usign the lower version of spring (i.e 2.x), you need to specify

```
<context:annotation-config>
```

To let the spring identify annotations, if you are using Higher versions (3.x, 4.x) of spring, you don't need to specify it.

and then annotate your classes with @Repository stereotype (Because you are usign it on Dao layer)

i.e

```
@Repository
class Am_campusentityJdbcDAO
```

if it need any dependencies, you just need to inject them using `@Autowired` annotation

in your case

```
@Autowired
Datasource datasource;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! :D

Answer (score 2):

You should think of using Hibernate/JPA and/or Spring Data JPA.

This way you won't have to write deep DAOs but just plain simple interfaces with a conventional naming with maybe some custom queries.

The next two links will help you:

- [Spring Data quick start](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/#quick-start)
- [Spring Data JPA Tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-getting-the-required-dependencies/)

Or if you like to use Spring Context XML to have an application blueprint, you could just use:

```
<bean id="Am_campusentityDAO" class="com.bdAlmamater.model.Am_campusentityJdbcDAO"/>
```

and autowire the DataSource field:

```
@Autowired
Datasource datasource;
```

Comment: Spring Data is really great!

Comment: @sahel how could this answers the question ?  you should probably provide answer instead of providing alternatives. Because I may not want to use Hibernate or Jpa

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera The question was: "or is there a shorter way?" Which implies an alternative, because there are no constraints AFAIK. Let me edit the answer and add another alternative.

Comment: @sahel What could see is, he means alternate way for not declaring Dao classes in bean configuration file. He has never specified about any ORMs , frameworks etc

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera exactly! What could YOU see. I've given a shorter alternative, just as you did. Why is this such a problem as the question was seeking for a shorter solution. As he uses Spring Context XML for configuration I don't see why he would like to use component scanning as you suggested. IMO the answer I gave is just as valid as yours.

Comment: @sahel I don't want to argue with you, I hope you get some maturity in future to understand what I mean to say. Please read this comments after few years

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera I don't think I will change my opinion in a few years. If you've seen that I maybe made a mistake and you are mature as you think you are, you could just kept it for yourself and gave the answer you thought was right. This is at least how it should work, the right answer gets a green tick, doesn't it? Hope we're done here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @sahel. In my next project I would probably take a look at JPA. It sounds good.